# WPF Textbox add custom spelling check system or extend existing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, spell-checking

I am looking into the power of the WPF textblock spellcheck enabled property, I noticed that this solution doesn't offer a grammar check solution. I was hoping I could do some form of inheritance that I add on a basic grammar check, checking for 'the the' or 'this this'. Really just doing a basic check for duplicates that are directly next to each other. Also I am looking to add the green underline just like word does. I don't want to add a reference to word, I want this to be it's own component.

Has anyone seen something like this, or is this not even possible inside of WPF and it's spell checking.

Comment: WPF does underline (in red) but no grammar or duplicate

Comment: I knew that, I was hoping to extend this feature set and add a green line for duplicates.

Comment: yeah, ok, I just comfirm. take care that it also works only if you install net languages packs. bye